# Use an Expression<Func> within an Expression<Func>

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

The below code works fine (throws no translation error):

```
string text = "someString";
string refId = "refId";
bool forward = true;
IQueryable<Tin> q = queryable.Where(o => forward ? text.IsGreaterThan(refId) : text.IsLessThan(refId));
var x = await q.ToArrayAsync();
```

`IsGreaterThan()` and `IsLessThan()` are methods that have been registered in `OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)` from dbContext, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54920200/entity-framework-core-guid-greater-than-for-paging/54929035#54929035). So the problem is not with those methods.

The below code doesn't work:

```
string refId = "refId";
Expression<Func<Tin, string>> key = obj => obj.Id;
bool forward = true;
IQueryable<Tin> q = queryable.Where(o => forward ? key.Compile()(o).IsGreaterThan(refId) : key.Compile()(o).IsLessThan(refId));
var x = await q.ToArrayAsync();
```

It throws the below error.

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Follow>
    .Where(f => f.FollowerId == __userId_0)
    .Where(f => Invoke(__Compile_1, f[Follow])
        .IsGreaterThan(__refId_2))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().
```

I understand why it fails. `Expression<Func<>>.Compile()` returns a `Func<>` and those cannot be used in Linq to Sql. So I've been looking for workarounds.

The most promising I found is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59086049/5920922). It worked as expected in the fiddle he provided, but for some reason, it didn't work for me.
My code after implementing his answer:

```
string refId = "refId";
Expression<Func<Tin, string>> key = obj => obj.Id;
bool forward = true;
Func<Tin, string> keyFunc = key.Compile();
Expression<Func<Tin, bool>> where = o => forward ? keyFunc(o).IsGreaterThan(refId) : keyFunc(o).IsLessThan(refId);
where.Replace(() => keyFunc, key);
IQueryable<Tin> q = queryable.Where(where);
var x = await q.ToArrayAsync();
```

Is there some other way to nest `Expression<Func<>>`s?

**EDIT**: As mentioned by @pinkfloydx33:

```
where.Replace(() => keyFunc, key);
```

should have been:

```
where = where.Replace(() => keyFunc, key);
```

Funny enough, I make this same mistake with `string.Replace()` a loooot.
It works fine now after this.

Comment: I don't believe EF supports nested Expressions... Some clarification on what you want to build as end result could help...

Comment: Btw... In Your example code of trying the expression visitor you're not reassigning the `where` variable. Expressions are immutable. So you need `where = where.Replace(...)` and the visitor should work

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Ahhh..... This was what was missing!! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature is not supported by EF, and i don't know why ;)
You have to install LINQKit and use `AsExpandable()` adn `Invoke` instead of `Compile`:

```cs
string refId = "refId";
Expression<Func<Tin, string>> key = obj => obj.Id;
bool forward = true;
IQueryable<Tin> q = queryable
  .AsExpandable()
  .Where(o => forward ? key.Invoke(o).IsGreaterThan(refId) : key.Invoke(o).IsLessThan(refId));
var x = await q.ToArrayAsync();
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'd rather not install a library for this one case. But this looks much cleaner. And I wonder about the performance of the solution I have now. If I have to do this expression nesting often, I may switch to using this.

Comment: Actually look closer to these libraries. What you have did it is nothing comparing to what they can do:
https://github.com/hazzik/DelegateDecompiler
and
https://github.com/axelheer/nein-linq